# Display correct labels in Grafana XY chart

Tags: grafana

I have a Grafana dashboard, in which there is an XY panel.

I have two data sources, which are in table format and of type instant. I do an Inner JOIN on the data, and can successfully use a series where I select the `Value #A` and `Value #B` respectively for each axis.

However the data for each point is not displayed in the panel when I hover over each point (Grafana v 9.4.3):

[image: New Grafana]

However the behaviour is different for an newer version of Grafana (v 10.0.1):

[image]

I *think* the panels should be more or less the same.

Does anyone know how to force the older version of Grafana to behave in the same way, so that I can see the values used for the point when I hover over it?

Comment: Can you show, are table views (slider on top of the graph) show the same (in terms of columns) results? Additionally, with XY Chart being in Beta even in 10, it's possible that there were some significant changes, and legend was simply one of them.

Comment: No @markalex, the table view shows eveything, not just value #A and value #B